# How can I autofill a field in my django form?

Tags: python, django, forms, fill

I am trying to create a very simple form for users to borrow book from a library and I have a button to borrow book that redirects user to another page.

Once the user is redirected all i want to allow him is to click submit or cancel for specific book.

My model for that:

```
class Borrowed(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    taken_date= models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    return_date= models.DateField(default=datetime.today()+timedelta(days=90))

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.person} borrowed {self.book}"
```

views.py:

```
def borrow(request, pk):
    book = Book.objects.get(id=pk)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # form = BorrowForm(instance=request.user.person)
        form = BorrowForm(request.POST, initial={Book: book.title})


        if form.is_valid():
            form = form.save(commit=False)
            form.person = request.user.person
            form.book = book.title
            form.save()
            return redirect('all_books')
    else:
        form = BorrowForm(initial=book.title)
    context = {'form': form, 'book': book}
    return render(request, 'rental/borrow.html', context)
```

forms.py

```
class BorrowForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Borrowed
        fields= ['book']
```

I don't know how and where exactly to do that because I am new to Django. Help would be appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

you have made mistake on passing the initial data use something like this to pass data

you have to put field name and its value like this

you have to put this in only in else statement because if you put that in the request.post method so if user delete that initial data and made that blank and save that but because of initial data it will be stored.

```
form = ContactForm(initial={'subject': 'Hi there!'})
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, the problem was I was passing book.title as initial. I should have used :

```
form = BorrowForm(request.POST, initial={'book':book.id})
```